# More efficient use of STStrMap

Tags: purescript

Is there a more efficient way of using the values in a STStrMap, other than freezeST to get the StrMap first? For example, I have a STStrMap which contain a bunch of functions. At some point, I want to call all the functions, returning the first Just value. This code works:

`runOpeners uri omap = do
  strmap <- omap >>= \omap' -> freezeST omap' -- convert from STStrMap to StrMap
  pure $ foldl (\acc o -> acc <|> o uri ) Nothing $ values strmap -- call opener functions`

But freezeST copies the map first, which is inefficient.